# No qualifying bean of type available

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.spring.dto.Car2' available

---

Controller.java -

```
public class Controller {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext  context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("configu.xml");
    Car2 c2 = (Car2) context.getBean(Car2.class);
    System.out.println(c2);
}
```

}

---

Car2.java -

```
@ToString @Component
public class Car2 {
    @Autowired
    private Engine engine;
}
```

---

Engine.java -

```
@Setter @ToString
public class Engine {
    private String modelYear;
   }
```

---

configu.xml -

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.dto.Car2" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean  class="com.spring.dto.Engine">
    <property name="modelYear" value="2015"></property>
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

---

please ignore the annotation @ToString and @Setter- I am using Lombok project for my simplicity.

Comment: Annotate your Engine class with component as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [ask].

Comment: @SangamBelose he has a Bean definition is his xml

Comment: You shoud use instead : `<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.dto" />`

Comment: base-package in config.xml should be base package i.e. from you have all classes wich you want spring to instantiate and  as rightly pointed out by Sangam..annonate your Engine class with @Component too,so it is available for autowiring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the error is here:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.dto.Car2" />
```

The value should be a package, not a class. Change it to "com.spring.dto", then it should work.