# No unique bean of type [com.Car] is defined: expected single bean but found 0:

Tags: spring

Hi i am new in Spring and i am using Spring base Annotation in my simple project i am trying to create using Stero Type Annotation have a look of my project

**Engine.java**

```
package com;

public class Engine {

    private String engname;

    public Engine() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        System.out.println("Engine Object Created");
    }

    public String getEngname() {
        return engname;
    }

    public void setEngname(String engname) {
        this.engname = engname;
    }

}
```

**Car.java**

```
package com;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class Car {

    @Autowired
    private Engine engine;

    public void printEngineData() {
        System.out.println("Engine Name"+engine.getEngname());
    }

}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

     <context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
     <context:annotation-config/>

     <bean class="com.Engine">
         <property name="engname" value="Audi Engine"></property>
     </bean>

</beans>
```

and my Test class is look like
**Client.java**
    package com;

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ap=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        Car c = (Car)ap.getBean(Car.class);
        c.printEngineData();
    }
}
```

I am running the Client.java class, it executes the Engine class Constructor and prints **Engine Object Created** after that it throws me **Exception** org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.

I am using spring3.2.0 for this project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46487567/no-qualifying-bean-of-type-available

Comment: ok but that answer not working for me can you please check where i am making mistake

Comment: Create a bean for 'Car' class as well in your XML configuration

Comment: yes when i created the car bean in xml file it working. can you please explain me this is the right concept <context:component-scan base-package="com"/> is this compulsory to make the car class bean in xml

Comment: The line "<context:component-scan base-package="com"/>" instruct Spring to check for bean classes in "com" and its sub packages. So as your both classes are in "com" package, so you should add above lines in your configurations

Comment: Second "Car c = (Car)ap.getBean(Car.class);" line means that you are retrieving a 'Car' bean,and so for that you should define a 'Car' bean in your xml configuration

Answer (score 0):

There are two facets mixed up, the xml configuration and the component scan. To get your Car class scanned, you have to use one of the correct annotations, e.g.

```
@Component
public class Car {
....
}
```

The other way is to define your `car` bean in the xml file, as already mentioned in the comments. Then you should delete the

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
```

Tag since this will scan all classes in any com.* package in your classpath for the @Component (or some other) annotation which may take a while, at least in large projects.
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In this program if you check applicationContext.xml file you have below line

Above line represent that you are using Autoscan with annotation for object creation so above Car class there should be @Component annotaion.